# Почему функция не прекращает работу по return

Tags: c++, c++11, qtcreator

Писал мини программу в Qt Creator. заметил странный баг при проверке (**ValidateVariant**) введенных данных (**GetVariant**). Если сначала ввести пустую строку, символы или неверный номер, а затем правильную команду, то функция вместо выхода заного себя запускает, вместо выхода.

```
bool ValidateVariant(string &str){
    if ((regex_match(str, regex("\\s"))) || str.empty()){
        cout << "\x1b[2C\x1b[0;31m"
                "Введена пустая строка."
                "\n\x1b[2C\x1b[0;37m>";
        return false;
    }
    if (str.find_first_not_of("1234567890") != string::npos){
        cout << "\x1b[2C\x1b[0;31m"
                "Введен текст. Должно быть число."
                "\n\x1b[2C\x1b[0;37m>";
        return false;

    }
    if (!(stoi(str) < 6 && stoi(str) > 0)){
        cout << "\x1b[2C\x1b[0;31m"
                "Нет комманды под таким номером."
                "\n\x1b[2C\x1b[0;37m>";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int GetVariant(){
    string variant("");
    while (getline(cin, variant)) {
        if (ValidateVariant(variant)) return stoi(variant);
        else GetVariant();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Translate your question into Russian or ask it [here](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: На то здесь и русский стак - если хочешь блеснуть английским, отправляйся на оригинал: stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закомментируйте/удалите эту строчку.

```
// else GetVariant();
```

Рекурсия здесь не нужна.

Comment: Ахахаха это такая глупая ошибка  =)

Comment: @ViktorBondar Бывает. Успехов!